# Can anyone tell me how to create an stand alone SWF launcher that loads the SWF

Tags: c#, .net, flash, swfloader

As Flash is going to be dead in few days. I want to know how I can create an .EXE file that loads the SWF file from the server and plays in that application.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to improve the quality of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use Web Browser component (a .NET Control). See page from [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-navigate-to-a-url-with-the-webbrowser-control). A good [tutorial #1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/webbrowser-control-in-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/).

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://yoursite.com/YourFlashFile.swf");
```

You can set width and height to be 100% of the window size.

**Option 2:** Use Flash component (a COM object). A good [tutorial #2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-play-flash-in-windows-forms-application-using-C-Sharp/).

Find and select`Shockwave Flash Object` in COM components. By default it's called `axShockwaveFlash1`.

```
this.axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "https://yoursite.com/YourFlashFile.swf";
```