# How to limit Flash Player FPS and resources in CefSharp?

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp to run a Flash game on a very low spec computer. I was wondering if there's any way to optimize Flash to use less resources on the computer, such as limiting frame rate, resources allowed, graphics mode, etc.

I know CefSharp has many command-line flags to choose from, but I'm unsure what do in regards to making CefSharp/Flash use less resources & CPU.

Thanks for any answers or suggestions.

Comment: To my knowledge the answer is no. It would only be if Chromium supported such a feature, and I've not seen reference to one.

Comment: **(1)** Try also using the official Adobe version of [Flash Player in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580645/2057709) because CEFSharp uses Google's alternate version called Pepper Flash and that's not always smooth. **(2)** If needed, here's [a link to the C# compatible plugin for Internet Explorer](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/download/?installer=FP_32_for_Internet_Explorer_-_ActiveX&os=Windows%207&browser_type=KHTML&browser_dist=Chrome&dualoffer=false&mdualoffer=true&stype=7693&d=McAfee_Security_Scan_Plus&d=McAfee_Safe_Connect)